# Java new Date() in print

Tags: java

just learning Java and I know this may sound stupid but I have to ask.

```
System.out.print(new Date());
```

I know that whatever is in the argument is converted to a string, the end value that is, 
`new Date()` returns a reference to a Date object. So how is it that it prints this?

```
Mon Aug 29 13:22:03 BST 2011
```

The only thing I can think of is somehow the function parses through all the data members gets their values converts them to a String and prints them.

If not how does it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you print something, the [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method of that object is called. So it is up to the individual class to provide an implementation that makes sense.

For reference, see

- **[Java Tutorial: The Object class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)**

And this is Date's toString() method:

```
public String toString() {
// "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
    index = 8;
}
convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');            // EEE
convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
if (zi != null) {
    sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
} else {
    sb.append("GMT");
}
sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The method `System.out.print(obj);` calls the `.toString()` method of the object. It's up to the class to define that method as it likes. If the object is `null` then "null" is printed.

If the class doesn't define its own `.toString()` method, the default implementation for the `Object` class applies, which essentially prints `@` followed by the hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

An `Object` has a [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which is a textualized representation of the Object. All java objects extends Object implicitly or explicitly. Some classes have overridden the `toString()` method (like `java.util.Date`).

So, when you do:

```
System.out.println(new Date());
```

It's "loosely" translated as

```
System.out.println(new Date().toString());
```

That's the default behaviour of Java.

---

Actually, the `out.println()` from `System` calls the `PrintStream.println(Object x)`, which (internally, in the code), does (`return (x == null)? "null" : x.toString()`).

If the subclassed Object doesn't override the `toString()` method, the `Object.toString` method is called instead (since all classes implicitly or explicitly extends `Object`).

Comment: I wish the books, mention what actually happens. They should be able to predict the questions that beginner will ask lol.
Your explanation is clear thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default the object's `toString()` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Each object in Java extends from Object. Object defines a method toString, that is responsible for converting the object to a string representation.

The default implementation in Object, on most JVMs, returns the full class name followed by "@" and a hex number, representing uniquely that object instance in the JVM.

The Date object overrides the toString method, returning the string you see printed.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` method calls the `toString` method on the new date object implicitly. `toString` is defined in `Object`, but is overwritten in Date as documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

In general: Everytime you use an object in a place where a String is expected, the `toString` method will be automagically called.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println accepts an object as an argument. As told before all Java classes inherit from Object.. This Object class contains a 'toString' method, and the println method simply calls the toString method from the object. Since all classes inherit from Object, every class has a toString method which can be called.